# In spring boot under resources the static and template is not created?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, spring-thymeleaf, spring-initializr

Under resources why the static and template folder is not created automatically?

[src/main/resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQXcp.jpg)

Is there any problem if i create the static and the template folder by my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every application needs these folders, and therefore it doesn't make sense to create them automatically.

Simply create it by yourself.